# How many FIDE-rated games must be played to obtain a *non* provisional rating?

Tags: rating, fide

I have a provisional FIDE rating of 1980 based on my score of 1 (two draws) out of 4 at a FIDE-rated tournament earlier this year; see: http://ratings.fide.com/card.phtml?event=2059100 where provisional rating is Rp.  I am playing in another FIDE-rated tournament next weekend and I seem to recall it may take as few as 9 games against FIDE-rated opponents to obtain an official (*non* provisional) rating, though I'm having a hard time authenticating this.

This is important to me as it's a 5-round tournament coming up and I want to know whether taking a bye may mean I have to play in yet another FIDE-rated tournament after this one to reach the plateau of 9, if that is indeed the correct figure.

Answer (score 4):

I want to add two details. First, FIDE does not have provisional ratings. The "Rp" you see on that page is your *performance* rating for that tournament. It is based on the rating of your opponents and your score in the tournament.

Second, only games against FIDE rated players count. You've probably figure that out as only 3 of your games were rated while you were thinking of playing 4 or 5.

Answer (score 1):

5 games against rated opponents played in a rated tournament.

Comment: Welcome to Chess SE! This might be the correct answer, but it would be nice to have an official reference confirming this. Could you please provide that?

Comment: Reference can be article 7 in https://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=172&view=article From july 2014 5 games are needed to get a rating.